# Prove the convergence of a sequence involving integrals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I need to prove the following:

Assume $f:[a,b] \to R$ is continous, $f(x)\leq0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, and $M=sup\{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$.Show that:

$$\{[\int [f(x)]^{n}dx]^{1/n}\} \to M$$

This result is clear when $f(x)=0$ because $M=0$ and the sequence of only zeros(since the integral is cero for all $a,b$ and $n$) converge to zero, but the other case, I do not know how to attached it because is a little bit confusing for me.Can you help me to prove this .I appreciate all your anwers, thank you I really need your help.

**I forgot something, which is this m in the step (M−ϵ)m(E)1/n≤[∫E|f(x)|ndx]1/n≤[∫ba|f(x)|ndx]1/n≤M(b−a)1/n. –**  @RRL?, **How can I do it with out the Lebesgue measure ? thanks**

Comment: I am confused by the formulation (in particular, if $n$ is even, how to choose the sign of the $n$-root): let $f(x)=-2$, $a=0,b=1$, $\int f(x)^{2k} =4^k$, and $\sqrt[2k]{4^k}=2$. Do you mean $f\geq 0$?

Comment: Do you integrate from $a$ to $b$ and do you average the integral by dividing by $b-a$? Also should you have $f(x) \geq 0$?

Comment: I am sorry yes is grater than zero

Answer (score 1):

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that $M - \epsilon < |f(x)| \leq M.$

Let E = $\{x \in [a,b]: M - \epsilon < |f(x)| < M\} = |f|^{-1}[( M - \epsilon,M))].$

Since $f$ is continuous, E is an open set and there is an interval $(\alpha,\beta) \subset E \subset [a,b]$.

Note that

$$\int_\alpha^{\beta} |f(x)|^ndx \leq  \int_a^b |f(x)|^ndx$$

Hence,

$$(M-\epsilon)\left( \beta-\alpha\right)^{1/n}\leq \left[\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} |f(x)|^{n}dx\right]^{1/n}\leq\left[\int_a^b |f(x)|^{n}dx\right]^{1/n}\leq M(b-a)^{1/n}.$$

Now use the squeeze property as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Then

$$(M- \epsilon)\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\beta-\alpha\right)^{1/n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\int_a^b |f(x)|^{n}dx\right]^{1/n}\leq M \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(b-a)^{1/n},$$

and for every $\epsilon > 0$,

$$M- \epsilon \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\int_a^b |f(x)|^{n}dx\right]^{1/n}\leq M $$

Hence,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\int_a^b |f(x)|^{n}dx\right]^{1/n} =  M $$

Comment: I think everything is good but which is that property ?

Comment: Ok :), but how can I conclude?

Comment: Which property -- first line?

Comment: no the  squeeze property as n→∞ :) but you remarked in your post, thank you, and I we didnt need the epsilon-delta definition for convergence then ?

Comment: The squeeze theorem puts the limit betwee $M -\epsilon$ and $M$ for any $\epsilon$ -- so the limit must be $M$.  We also use the fact that $q^{1/n} \rightarrow 0 $ for $q>0$

Comment: ok thanks :) then with this we are done isnt?

Comment: Yes -- you're welcome

Comment: I forgot something, which is this m in the step (M−ϵ)m(E)1/n≤[∫E|f(x)|ndx]1/n≤[∫ba|f(x)|ndx]1/n≤M(b−a)1/n.

Comment: Here I am using $m$ for Lebesgue measure.  So $\int_E dx = m(E)$  Since $E \subset [a,b]$ all we need is $(M-\epsilon)[\int_E dx]^{1/n} \leq [\int_E f dx]^{1/n}\leq [\int_a^b f dx]^{1/n}$ and the LHS still converges to $M - \epsilon$.

Comment: well we havent seen taht :(, haow can I do it with out it, can you edit your answer please :)

Comment: thanks for the edit, but I cant use that function, can you help me to do it with out it :), thank you

Comment: So you want a proof using only continuity of f -- we cant use integral of a characteristic function. Is that right?  That is easy to fix because $E = f^{-1}(M-\epsilon,M)$ is an open set.  I  can fix above if you are still interested.

Comment: Yes please because we haven't seen the lebesgue measure please I'll appreciate that

Comment: What is a characteristic function?

Comment: OK - I have edited the post. The proof now uses no Lebesgue measure -- it just uses the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Can your help me with Series and sequences convergence with a certain condition please? I appreciate your help with that

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the $L^n$-norm converges to $L^\infty$-norm as $n\to +\infty$, i.e.
$\left( \int_a^b f^n \right)^{1/n}=\|f\|_{L^n}\to \|f\|_{L^\infty}...$

Comment: we havent seen that yet :) but thanks for your answer

Comment: The question is *how* to prove this.